# finding the sum of numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, processing

I was trying to find the sum of an array of numbers in Processing. but when i tried calculating it using the code below, I found the values being continuously increased since the forloop is running. Is there any way that I can get the sum of the numbers in the array other than adding a noLoop function or doing the addition inside void setup?

It would be a great help if someone can help me with this. Many thanks in advance

Cheers, Yousuf.

```
float sum = 0;
float [] f = {12, 2, 4, 6, 23};

void setup() {

  size(600, 600);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {

  for (int i =0; i<f.length; i++) {

    sum +=f[i];
  }
  println(sum);//// I only wanted to print the first value of sum, which is the total of the numbers listed array of numbers.
}
```

Comment: do you reset sum variable in any place, if not the value in it will be increased by sum of f values each time draw function is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset the `sum` variable before you run the loop, otherwise it will still contain the previous sum.

```
void draw() {
  sum = 0;
  for (int i =0; i<f.length; i++) {
    sum +=f[i];
  }
  println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize sum as a local variable within the draw function instead of a global. That way it will automatically be reset every time you call draw.

Comment: Or just do all in `setup()`, or use `noLoop()`